# How can I view the ASPNETDB database from a sample ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

A basic ASP.NET MVC app appears to store user info in App_Data\ASPNETDB.  How can I view tables in that database using VS2008?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.  My problem was that as a Data Source I was choosing "Microsoft SQL Server" instead of "Microsoft SQL Server Database File", a choice a little further down the list.